# Rails two table join depending on filled values in has_many table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I need to create a query which will return all buyers depending on there meetings

I have 2 models

```
class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :meetings
end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :buyer
end

Buyers(id, name)
Meetings(id, buyer_id, value)
```

Now i need to create a query which will return all the buyers who have no meeting with value false

I mean from this records:

```
Buyers:

1, Toms
2, Ingus

Meetings

1, 1, true
2, 1, false
3, 2, true
4, 2, true
```

Only Ingus should be selected

EDIT:

Well i guess quesry looks something like this

```
select * from Buyers where id in (select buyer_id from Meetings where value = false group by buyer_id having count(*) = 0)
```

but how to get in in Rails so its pretty?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
Buyer.joins(:meetings).where("meetings.value = ?", false).distinct
```

Comment: This is wrong, it will return buyers, who meetings are true but others false. And if i am not mistaken it will return multiple similiar records with same buyer

Comment: i have edited that, you can check, either you can use distinct or it just like select("DISTINCT(field name)")

Comment: You are missing my point. It does not matter if you use distinct if there is a buyer with at least one meeting which have value true, than it will select it. I need only thous who have all true.